# How to open a nested child PreferenceScreen in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceScreen that is defined in XML that serves all the preferences for my application. This PreferenceScreen also has a child PreferenceScreen nested within it. My implementing class is called PreferencesActivity. I know I can open the main Preferences window via startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class)); but how do I go about opening the child PreferenceScreen via an Intent?

Answer (score 4):

i researched a while on this topic for my project Theft Aware (http://www.theftaware.com) (a little bit advertisement... :-) and i found the solution:

```
PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen(); // gets the main preference screen     
screen.onItemClick(null, null, INDEX , 0); // click on the item
```

where INDEX is the position of the item you want to open on the screen

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I am wondering if this can be adapted to make the positioning of the items agnostic.

Comment: I've implemented the method by Reinhard to solve it more generally, see the link in my answer to my question!

Answer (score 3):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-a-android-dialogpreference-created-with-xml-from-code/4869034#4869034) for a more general solution based on Reinhard's idea, finally!

Comment: Works, but if you're using PreferenceCategories be sure to read down for the code by deepak patel and use that, otherwise 'getOrder' will not work