# Programmatically start DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a class defined like this

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogPreference {
```

and in the preference.xml

```
<com.package.pak.MyDialog
    android:key="my_key" android:title="Title"
    android:dialogTitle="title"
    android:dialogIcon="@drawable/app_icon" android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="Ok" />
```

My question is how can I programatically start the MyDialog ?
Is there something I can call like an intent or ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look onto this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-or-simulate-a-click-on-a-android-preference-which-was-created-with/4869034#4869034

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896

Answer (score -1):

DialogPreference has a method performClick()

Comment: I think that is not correct. Can you provide a reference where you can see that method documented?

Comment: This is not answer to Question