# Android: Is there a way to show DialogPreference from code?

Tags: android, android-preferences, dialog-preference

I want to open some preferences (which are made by extending DialogPreference) on first app startup. Also, these preferences are used as usual preferences.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

**EDIT:**

I have my custom preference, made like this:

```
public class CitySelectPreference extends DialogPreference  {
// Some code here
}
```

And as the solution I want it to be shown from the code, without the need of user getting to preference screen.

Comment: what version are you compiling against because depending on that there are a few ways

Comment: I'm targeting android 2.2... Also, found some answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4869034/1048087

Comment: i may be misunderstanding your question, but what is wrong with displaying the dialog preference in the oncreate method of the activity?

Comment: how can I do this? I have no access to the CitySelectPreference object from arbitrary code...

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @artman Check Pdroid's solution, it seems to be working. I didn't try it as this problem is not actual for me anymore. Also, take a notice here if it works, please.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this :

```
CitySelectPreference preference = (CitySelectPreference) findPreference("city_pref_key")

//You have to set a key to yout PreferenceScreen
PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("screen_pref_key");

//Retrieve the index of the preference in preferenceScreen
int index = preference.getOrder();

//Perform a click
screen.onItemClick(null, null, index, 0);
```