# How to open or simulate click on android ListPreference, which is inside preference category?

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I'm trying to open programatically a ListPreference, which exist inside PreferenceCategory. The XML structure is something like:

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    android:key="pref_screen" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="Category"
        andorid:key="pref_category">
        <ListPreference
            android:key="pref_list"
            android:title="List" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My goal is to open "pref_list" programatically, and display it to the user. I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-or-simulate-a-click-on-an-android-preference-created-with-xml-prog) topic, offering this solution:

```
// the preference screen your item is in must be known
PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("pref_screen");

// the position of your item inside the preference screen above
int pos = findPreference("pref_list").getOrder();

// simulate a click / call it!!
screen.onItemClick( null, null, pos, 0 );
```

This works perfectly for a PreferenceScreen without PreferenceCategory, but I can't get it working for my case (When the ListPreference is located inside PreferenceCategory).

How can I modify this for my case? Or is there any other solution?

I couldn't find in PreferenceCategory a method, similar to `onItemClick()` of PreferenceScreen. Changing 'pos' for the `getOrder()` value of my PreferenceCategory did not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very old thread but I've just had similar problem so here my short solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17919879/5377293) one

```
    ListAdapter listAdapter = getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter();

    for (int itemNumber = 0; itemNumber < listAdapter.getCount(); itemNumber++)
        if (listAdapter.getItem(itemNumber).equals(findPreference("pref_list")))
            getPreferenceScreen().onItemClick(null, null, itemNumber, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Offering a different solution, simulating a finger touch:

Use `View.getLocationOnScreen()` and/or `getLocationInWindow()` to get the position of the list item. So you can find a `width` and a `height` to simulate a click.

```
    MotionEvent me=MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, width, height, 0);
    rootView.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    me=MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, width, height, 0);
    rootView.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    me.recycle();
```