# Opening ListPreference when PreferenceActivity starts

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I wanted to open ListPreference without PreferenceActivity. But as I use ActionBar Sherlock and don't have time to write custom ListView to work as ListPreferences I decided to use temporary solution from this thread:
[How to open or simulate a click on an android Preference, created with XML, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-or-simulate-a-click-on-an-android-preference-created-with-xml-prog/4869034#4869034)

I have PreferenceActivity:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        int pos = findPreference("timeZone").getOrder();
        preferenceScreen.onItemClick(null, null, pos, 0);

    }

}
```

And prefs.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="mainPreferences" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="Default"
        android:entries="@array/prefs_time_zones_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/prefs_time_zones_values"
        android:key="timeZone"
        android:summary="@string/prefs_time_zones_summary"
        android:title="@string/prefs_time_zones_title" />
    (...)
    (...)
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I start PrefsActivity, my ListPreference (with key "timeZone") appears and works correctly. The problem occurs when I rotate the phone while the list is open. After the rotation, the second list is created. So when I choose an item from the list and the list disappear, the second one is still present (with original item selected). **How to avoid creating the second list while the rotation?**

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but easiest solution, **ADD**

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

to your activity in your manifest...

```
<activity android:name="com.your.activity"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Comment: Not "not the best", that is the worst solution.

Comment: @AppiDevo: then you tell which is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution, just check if `savedInstanceState` is null. If yes, call `onItemClick`.