# Switch to a nested PreferenceScreen from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-preferences

How do I open up into a nested PreferenceScreen to a particular preference from an activity (such as through an intent)?

Example:

```
<PreferenceScreen

 ...
<!-- opens a subscreen of settings -->
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="sub_menu_key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Submenu">

    ...

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="category_key"
        android:title="Category">
     ...

        <Preference
            android:key="tos_key"
            android:title="Terms of Service" />
     ...
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
...
```

Is there a way to open directly to where "Terms of Service" is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delare the specified Preference class in your `onResume()` method. In my case I was using `SwitchPreference` class, therefore the code would be like - `SettingsActivity.class`

```
public static class PrivacyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    public SwitchPreference switchPreference;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        switchPreference = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("privacy_notice_check");
    }

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_privacy);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
}
```

Then in the activity where you want to use the `PreferenceFragment` value, just use the `SharedPreference` object to call the values and trigger it.

If you want the `SharedPreference` logic just comment below.

Comment: I worked on this preference activity to display privacy notice to people if the switchprefence was set to ON otherwise do not display the notice if set to off.

Answer (score -1):

From an Activity (es: Main Activity) you can use an explicit intent

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button goToPreference;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    goToPreference = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goToButton);
    goToPreference.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // when you click go to Preference
            Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, UserSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Layout: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="it.uniba.di.ivu.di.sms16.gruppox.examplesettings.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go To Preference"
    android:id="@+id/goToButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UserSettingsActivity is an activity that extends PreferenceActivity and allows you to view preference

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if(key.equals("lenguage_preference"))
    {
         // TO DO
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Lenguage">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="lenguage_preference"
        android:title="Change Lenguage"
        android:summary="Choose yout language"
        android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference2"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference2"
        android:dialogTitle="choose favourite language" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Distance">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="distance_preference"
        android:title="Distance"
        android:summary="Change distance"
        android:entries="@array/entries_list_preference"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryvalues_list_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="choose favourite distance" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="entries_list_preference"
    translatable="false">

    <item>2 (km)</item>
    <item>1 (km)</item>
    <item>500 (m)</item>
    <item>200 (m)</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="entryvalues_list_preference"
    translatable="false">
    <item>2000</item>
    <item>1000</item>
    <item>500</item>
    <item>200</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="entries_list_preference2"
    translatable="false">
    <item>Italian</item>
    <item>English</item>
    <item>French</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="entryvalues_list_preference2"
    translatable="false">
    <item>it</item>
    <item>en</item>
    <item>fr</item>

</string-array>
```

> Is there a way to open directly to "Terms of Service"?

I think you can refer to [How to open or simulate a click on an android Preference, created with XML, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805896/how-to-open-or-simulate-a-click-on-an-android-preference-created-with-xml-prog/4869034#4869034)

Comment: By going directly to "Terms of Service", I just mean going to the view where you will see that preference. Moving directly to a PreferenceScreen submenu. But thanks for this suggestion, I'll look into this as well.